# Clock page replacement algorithm - Already existing pages

Tags: algorithms, paging, virtual-memory

When simulating the clock page replacement algorithm, when a reference comes in which is already in memory, does the clock hand still increment?

Here is an example:

With 4 slots, using the clock page replacement algorithm

Reference list: 1 2 3 4 1 2 5 1 3 2 4 5

Initial list would look like this:

```
-> [1][1]
   [2][1]
   [3][1]
   [4][1]
```

The next reference to insert would be 1, then 2. Would the hand still point at 1 after 1, and after 2 ? In other words, after inserting the 5, would the clock look like this :

```
-> [5][1]
   [2][0]
   [3][0]
   [4][0]
```

?

Answer (score 9):

I think this example can clarify all your doubts.

For example:
Assumes main memory is empty at the start
page reference sequence is:
`3 2 3 0 8 4 2 5 0 9 8 3 2` one reference bit per frame (called the "used" bit)

```
  P   U   3    P   U   2   P   U   3   P   U   0   P   U   8   P   U  4
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|   | 0 |*   | 3 | 1 |   | 3 | 1 |   | 3 | 1 |   | 3 | 1 |   | 3 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|   | 0 |    |   | 0 |*  | 2 | 1 |   | 2 | 1 |   | 2 | 1 |   | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|   | 0 |    |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |*  |   | 0 |*  | 0 | 1 |   | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|   | 0 |    |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |*  | 8 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|   | 0 |    |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |   |   | 0 |*
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+----  


  P   U   2    P   U   5   P   U   0   P   U   9   P   U   8   P   U  3
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| 3 | 1 |*   | 3 | 1 |*  | 5 | 1 |   | 5 | 1 |   | 5 | 1 |   | 5 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| 2 | 1 |    | 2 | 1 |   | 2 | 0 |*  | 2 | 0 |*  | 9 | 1 |   | 9 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| 0 | 1 |    | 0 | 1 |   | 0 | 0 |   | 0 | 1 |   | 0 | 1 |*  | 0 | 1 |*
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| 8 | 1 |    | 8 | 1 |   | 8 | 0 |   | 8 | 0 |   | 8 | 0 |   | 8 | 1 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| 4 | 1 |    | 4 | 1 |   | 4 | 0 |   | 4 | 0 |   | 4 | 0 |   | 4 | 0 |
+---+---+    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+----  


  P   U   2    P   U   
+---+---+    +---+---+ 
| 5 | 1 |*   | 5 | 0 | 
+---+---+    +---+---+ 
| 9 | 1 |    | 9 | 0 |
+---+---+    +---+---+
| 0 | 0 |    | 2 | 1 |   
+---+---+    +---+---+  
| 8 | 0 |    | 8 | 0 |*
+---+---+    +---+---+ 
| 3 | 1 |    | 3 | 1 |  
+---+---+    +---+---+  

* = indicates the pointer which identifies the next location to scan 
P = page# stored in that frame 
U = used flag, 
0 = not used recently 
1 = referenced recently

This is called linear scanning algorithm or Second chance algorithm, used in BSD Linux. 
Generally it is implemented as a circular queue.
```

Comment: Could you give an explanation of what this means, in terms of text? It is a nice diagram, but such diagrams are useless when we don't know what it means.

Answer (score 8):

If a reference arrives for a page already in memory, then the replacement algorithm doesn't get invoked at all.

The [clock replacement algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Clock) is trying to achieve some of the benefits of LRU replacement, but without the massive overhead of manipulating the LRU bits on every page hit.

A page can be in one of three states:

1. Present in memory and the `recently-used` bit is `true`.  In this case there will be no page fault when an access happens to the page, so no bits will change.
2. Present in memory but the `recently-used` bit is `false`.  In this case the page is also marked in the page table in such a way that if the page is accessed a page fault will occur.  (And if the page fault occurs in this case, the only thing the page fault handler does is change the state to `recently-used`.)
3. The page is not present in memory.  In this case we look at the `clock-hand`.  While the `clock-hand` is pointing to a page with the `recently-used` bit set `true` we flip the `recently-used` bit to `false`, and then increment `clock-hand` to point to the next page.  When we find a page with `recently-used` already cleared, that is the page we replace.  Then we mark the new page as `recently-used` and increment the `clock-hand` to the *next* page.

Clock is, at heart, a probabilistic algorithm for approximating LRU.  If the rate at which the page is being accessed is much higher than the rate at which the `clock-hand` is coming back around to the same page then the page has a high probability of being marked `recently-used`.  If the rate at which the page is being accessed is low compared to the rate at which the `clock-hand` is coming back around, then the page is more likely to be in state *not* `recently-used`.  The most recently-used page will never be replaced.  (Why?)